# Remote development

Tags: eclipse, ide, netbeans, remote-debugging

I need IDE for remote debug. Local host on Windows xp and remote is on Linux.

I doubts between Eclipse and netBeans EDE.

Can anyone give me advice with that?

Comment: Thats completely language dependent. Could you give us more details?

Comment: I developing c++ application (Video server no GUI).